# want to bring references/bibliography without new section

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Hi I am working on a document where I don't want to have any empty space before bibliography starts. Even don't want the bibliography title. For now I deleted the heading, but still the space remains. Can anybody please suggest me how can I get rid of the space?
This is what I tried.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{report}
%All the packages that I needed. 
\renewcommand{\bibname}{} %The heading Bibliography gone
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%All text
{{\footnotesize}
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
 % Style BST file % or add {bmc_article}
 \bibliography{compbio2014} }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Basically I want the references to be started just after the last section text with new line. But no section break. So far I was using wither plain, or bmc_article bst file. 
Any help will be really great.
Thanks,
Mitra.

Comment: If `biblatex` is an option, you could do this very easily. With traditional `bibtex` a package like `natbib` can help with customisation but I don't remember about this specifically. (Certainly `biblatex` gives a lot more flexibility.)

Answer (score 4):

You will basically need to rewrite the `thebibliography` environment to remove the sectioning that is done.  The default is to use a `\chapter*` section with a report class.  By redefining, you end up with basically just starting a new paragraph.

The code below demonstrates:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{report}
%All the packages that I needed. 

% This is not strictly necessary with the modification given
\renewcommand{\bibname}{} %The heading Bibliography gone

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {%\chapter*{\bibname}% <-- this line was commented to remove any sectioning that occurs
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text
\usepackage{filecontents} % Just for illustration

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{paperOne,
  author = "Abedon, S. T. and Hyman, P. and Thomas, C.",
  year = "2003",
  title = "Experimental examination of bacteriophage latent-period evolution as a response to bacterial availability",
  journal = "Applied and Environmental Microbiology",
  volume = "69",
  pages = "7499--7506"
}
@incollection{paperTwo,
  author = "Abedon, S. T.",
  title = "Lysis and the interaction between free phages and infected cells",
  pages = "397--405",
  booktitle = "Molecular biology of bacteriophage T4",
  editor = "Karam, Jim D. Karam and Drake, John W. and Kreuzer, Kenneth N. and Mosig, Gisela
            and Hall, Dwight and Eiserling, Frederick A. and Black, Lindsay W. and Kutter, Elizabeth
            and Carlson, Karin and Miller, Eric S. and Spicer, Eleanor",
  publisher = "ASM Press, Washington DC",
  year = "1994"
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%All text
\lipsum[1] % Add some dummy text
\nocite{*} % Cite the references you want to include...

% Call bibliography as normal
{{\footnotesize}
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
 % Style BST file % or add {bmc_article}
 \bibliography{\jobname} }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

This will give:

[image: example from code]